# Not able to create custom fields using deploy() call

Tags: metadata-api, deployment

Im trying to create a new custom field using metadata api,  deploy() call.

I'm using this [code](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1api/Content/meta_quickstart_java_sample.htm)

Also I have followed this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22486/using-deploy-to-create-a-new-custom-object-not-working-and-no-errors)

My directory structure is like this

```
components.zip
--package.xml
--Objects
----Account.object
--Profiles
----Admin.profile
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Admin</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>31.0</version>
</Package>
```

Account.object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

   <!--.....fields removed.........-->
   *emphasized text*

    <fields>
        <fullName>Website</fullName>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    </fields>
   <fields>
    <fullName>test__c</fullName>
    <caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
    <description>Dummy field</description>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>test</label>
    <length>18</length>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>true</unique>
</fields>

        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.NAME</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.SITE</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.PHONE1</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>CORE.USERS.ALIAS</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
    </searchLayouts>
    <sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
    <webLinks>
        <fullName>Billing</fullName>
        <availability>online</availability>
        <displayType>link</displayType>
        <encodingKey>UTF-8</encodingKey>
        <hasMenubar>true</hasMenubar>
        <hasScrollbars>true</hasScrollbars>
        <hasToolbar>true</hasToolbar>
        <height>600</height>
        <isResizable>true</isResizable>
        <linkType>url</linkType>
        <masterLabel>Billing</masterLabel>
        <openType>newWindow</openType>
        <position>none</position>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <showsLocation>true</showsLocation>
        <showsStatus>true</showsStatus>
        <url>http://www.genwatt.com/genwatt/billing.htm?actname={!Account_Name}</url>
    </webLinks>
</CustomObject>
```

Admin.profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <custom>false</custom>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.AccountNumber</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.AccountSource</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.AnnualRevenue</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.BillingAddress</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.CleanStatus</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.DandbCompanyId</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Description</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.DunsNumber</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Fax</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Industry</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Jigsaw</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.NaicsCode</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.NaicsDesc</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.NumberOfEmployees</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.OLD_ID8RHM5SI0OSADMLQ__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Ownership</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.ParentId</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Phone</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Rating</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.SLA__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.ShippingAddress</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Sic</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.SicDesc</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Site</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.TickerSymbol</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.Tradestyle</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Type</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Website</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.YearStarted</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.dmask_custom_field0__c</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Account.test__c</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>Account</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
    <recordTypeVisibilities>
        <default>false</default>
        <recordType>Account.Willi</recordType>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </recordTypeVisibilities>
    <recordTypeVisibilities>
        <default>false</default>
        <recordType>Account.Yoana</recordType>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </recordTypeVisibilities>
    <recordTypeVisibilities>
        <default>false</default>
        <recordType>Account.recType</recordType>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </recordTypeVisibilities>
    <recordTypeVisibilities>
        <default>true</default>
        <recordType>Account.recType1</recordType>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </recordTypeVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>standard-Account</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <userLicense>Salesforce</userLicense>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ActivateContract</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ActivateOrder</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AllowUniversalSearch</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AllowViewKnowledge</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ApiEnabled</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ApproveContract</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AssignPermissionSets</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AssignTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AuthorApex</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CanInsertFeedSystemFields</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CanUseNewDashboardBuilder</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterFileLink</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterInternalUser</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterInviteExternalUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterOwnGroups</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ContentAdministrator</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ConvertLeads</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateCustomizeDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateCustomizeFilters</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateCustomizeReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateDashboardFolders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreatePackaging</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateReportFolders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateWorkspaces</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CustomizeApplication</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DeleteActivatedContract</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DeleteTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DistributeFromPersWksp</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditActivatedOrders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditBillingInfo</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditBrandTemplates</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditCaseComments</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditEvent</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditHtmlTemplates</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditKnowledge</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditMyDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditMyReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditOppLineItemUnitPrice</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditPublicDocuments</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditPublicFilters</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditPublicTemplates</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditReadonlyFields</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditTask</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EmailMass</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EmailSingle</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EnableNotifications</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ExportReport</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ImportLeads</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ImportPersonal</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>InstallPackaging</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageAnalyticSnapshots</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageAuthProviders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageBusinessHourHolidays</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCallCenters</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCases</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCategories</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageContentPermissions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageContentProperties</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageContentTypes</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCustomPermissions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCustomReportTypes</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageDashbdsInPubFolders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageDataCategories</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageDataIntegrations</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageDynamicDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageEmailClientConfig</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageExchangeConfig</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageInteraction</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageInternalUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageIpAddresses</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageKnowledge</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageKnowledgeImportExport</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageLeads</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageLoginAccessPolicies</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageMobile</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageNetworks</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManagePackageLicenses</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManagePasswordPolicies</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageProfilesPermissionsets</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageQuotas</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageRemoteAccess</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageReportsInPubFolders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSearchPromotionRules</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSharing</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSolutions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSynonyms</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageUnlistedGroups</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>MassInlineEdit</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>MergeTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ModerateChatter</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ModifyAllData</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>NewReportBuilder</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>OverrideForecasts</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>PublishPackaging</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ResetPasswords</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>RunReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ScheduleReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SendSitRequests</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ShareInternalArticles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SolutionImport</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>TransferAnyCase</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>TransferAnyEntity</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>TransferAnyLead</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>UseTeamReassignWizards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewAllData</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewAllForecasts</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewAllUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewDataCategories</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewEventLogFiles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewHelpLink</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewMyTeamsDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewPublicDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewPublicReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewSetup</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Problem is, I am able to run the code successfully, and get

> Status is: Succeeded The file components.zip was successfully deployed

But, I dont see the new field created. test__c is the field Im trying to create.

Any inputs will be truly appreciated.
Note: I have removed some part here in Account.object to bypass character limit of stackexchange.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work for you, so I won't put this as an answer, but you might like to try my team's product https://gearset.com to try your deployment. It's currently free and takes about 30s to get started with so you might want to try it whilst you wait for another answer :)

Comment: What tool are you using to execute this deployment? If ANT, is your checkOnly set to true? If so, set that to false or remove that attribute and it should work.

Comment: @KevinBoyle  Im using Java code referred in the question to deploy. Any help with java code would help

Comment: @Sridhar  Im using Java code referred in the question to deploy. Any help with java code would help

Comment: @user70523 The java code set the API version to 29 while the URL points to 33. I would sync both to 29.  That said, I dont have much experience with the Java code but I am willing to spend some time with you. Drop me a line at sridhar at dreamfactory dot com and I will setup some time today.   Good luck!

Comment: Or better, sync both to v33. That is obviously more recent.      And the biggest issue is that people package components improperly. Make sure that you put everything under unpackaged folder before zipping the metadata.